# Редактирование содержимого MySQL через PHP для таблиц

Tags: php, mysql

Суть такова что я пытался редактировать MySQL бд через php, но у меня в базе данных очень много таблиц и хотелось, чтоб когда в форме я прописывал имя таблицы php само выбирало его

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
<title>Админ-панель</title>
</head>
<body>
help me
<form method="POST"><p>Введите имя таблицы</p>
    <input type="text" name="table">
    <p>Введите id телефона</p>
    <input type="number" name="id">
    <p>Введите цену</p>
    <input type="number" name="price">
<button type="submit"></button>
</form>

<?php
    require '../connect.php';

    if(isset($_POST['price']) && isset($_POST['table']) && isset($_POST['id'])){

    $id = htmlentities(mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['id']));
    $price = htmlentities(mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['price']));
    $table = htmlentities(mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['table']));

    $query ="UPDATE $table SET price = '$price' WHERE id = $id";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($connection)); 

    if($result)
        echo "<span style='color:blue;'>Данные обновлены</span>";
}





?>
```

Comment: и в чем проблема?

Comment: я пытаюсь зададть таблицу в форме но у меня он не обновляет не знаю почему